# Непонятное поведение base_convert

Tags: php

Не могу понять как правильно перевести 16тиричное число в двоичное в php.

Есть два варианта:

```
print base_convert(0xf, 16, 2)."\n";
print base_convert("f", 16, 2)."\n";
```

На выходе получаем:

```
10101
1111
```

**UPD**
Правильнее вопрос будет звучать так:
С какого бодуна стандартная функция переводит 16ричное 0xf в десятичное 15 и потом отдельно каждую цифру переводит в двоичный код с результатом 10101,
вместо ожидаемого 1111 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для PHP 0xf это десятичное число:

```
print base_convert(0xf, 10, 2)."\n"; // => 1111
```

Правильно так:

```
print base_convert("0xf", 16, 2)."\n"; // => 1111
```